# How to update a column in the local Database after inserting online

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have two databases, one local called localDB with columns fname(varchar), lname(varchar), sync(bit) and the other online called onlineDB with same columns fname(varchar), lname(varchar). The sync in the localDB is set to 0.
I want when I insert to the onlineDB, the sync in the localDB will be updated to 1.

```
public void syncData() {

    String fetchFromLocal = "SELECT fname, lname FROM localDB WHERE sync = 0";

    try 
    {
        PreparedStatement pst = conn.getConnect().prepareStatement(fetchFromLocal);             
        ResultSet res = pst.executeQuery();

        while(res.next())
        {
            String fname = res.getString("fname");
            String lname = res.getString("lname");

            if(interConnect.netIsAvailable())
            {       

                String insertOnline = " INSERT INTO onlineDB values('"+fname+"', '"+lname+"')";
                PreparedStatement pstOnline = conn.getConnectOnline().prepareStatement(insertOnline);
                pstOnline.executeUpdate();
                System.out.println("Insert Online a Success");

                conn.getConnectOnline().close();


            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("No Internet Connection");
                break;
            }


        }
catch(Exception)
{
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: So what's the problem?

Comment: If you need to execute an update on your local database after each insert to your remote database, your local database table will need to have a unique key.  Does it?

Comment: The problem here is after inserting to the onlineDB, i want the column in the localDB called sync to be updated to 1 since by default it's zero(0) so that when data are inserted into the localDB again it will not insert duplicate data